# is it possible to examine EXCEL dmp file?

Tags: excel, com-interop, windbg

I have a COM dll that works fine in a excel 2007. I'm trying to get it work with excel 2010, and it seems to work fine at first, and then the excel suddenly cruses, and produce a .dmp file.

1. Does excel.interop version 12 can be used on excel 2010?
2. Is it possible to examin the dmp file that produced after the crush, and if so how? (tried windbg, i have no idea how to use it)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Excel.Interop version 12 should work with Excel 2010 because COM components must be backward compatible (the interfaces found in Office 2010 must be compatible with the ones that exist in Office 2007)
The first step to carry out with your dump file is to load it in the debugger, setup the symbols correctly ('.symfix') and then launch the '!analyze -v' command. If the produced analysis and the callstack doesn't help you to pinpoint the problem, then you'll need advanced skills to debug the problem (memory corruption, debugging, ...).